# Object oriented CRUD with Mysqli

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I'm trying to learn OOP programming in PHP. So far i got couple of basic things but i don't know how to echo my results into the page. I made up Database class and Category class i wanna echo the results from read function but i don't know how to do that. Can someone help me refactor this so i can use both classes?

**This is my code**

```
class Database {
private $_connection;
private $_host = "localhost";
private $_username = "root";
private $_password = "";
private $_database = "cmsi";

// Conect to database is private and can only be used by getConection function result is returned object of mysqli class
//can be seen in var_dump() function
private function conect() {
    //$this refers to class Database and her functions and propertys are being acsessed via -> sign
    $this->_connection = new mysqli($this->_host, $this->_username,
                                    $this->_password, $this->_database);

    // Error handling
    if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
        trigger_error("Failed to conencto to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error(),
                      E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    return $this->_connection;

}
//Safest way to iniate conection
public function getConection(){
    return $this -> conect();
}
}


 class Category{
private $db_sql;
public function  __construct($db){
    $this->db_sql = $db;
}

public function read(){
    $conection = $this->db_sql;
    $query = "Select * from category";
    $result = $conection -> query($query);
    return $result;
   }

 }

$db = new Database();
$conection = $db->getConection();
$obj = new Category($conection);
$obj->read();
```

Comment: at the end: `$result = $obj->read(); var_dump($result);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just store the result set in a variable and loop through it, like this:

```
// your code

$db = new Database();
$conection = $db->getConection();
$obj = new Category($conection);

// store the result set
$result_set = $obj->read();

// loop through the result set
while($row = $result_set->fetch_array()){

    // your code

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i have just follow up  question. Is this proper OOP code or I'm complicating logic to much?

Comment: @L.Lawliet This is a good start for OOPs, but you should consider using [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) at later point of time.